# VSCode: tasks.json: dotnet build output parameter fails with MSBUILD : error MSB1001:

Tags: visual-studio-code, msbuild, .net-core, vscode-tasks

VSCode tasks.json args do not parse as expected to MSBuild

I want to change the output to another directory.
Addint "-o Z:/${workspaceFolderBasename}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/" into my dotnet build args did not work.
(It errors with MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch)

Solution: Add two args "-o" and "OutputPath" instead of "-o OutputpPath"

tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "process",
        "args": [
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Core3WinForms.csproj",
            // "-o Z:/${workspaceFolderBasename}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/" // that one won't work
            "-o",
            "Z:/${workspaceFolderBasename}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
}
```

output:

> > Executing task: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build >C:\Dev\NoControl\Core3WinForms/Core3WinForms.csproj -o >Z:/Core3WinForms/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/ <
>
> Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 16.0.225-preview+g5ebeba52a1 für .NET Core
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
> MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unbekannter Schalter.
>   Schalter: -o Z:/Core3WinForms/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/
>
> Informationen zur Schaltersyntax erhalten Sie, wenn Sie "MSBuild /help" eingeben.
>   The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
>
> > Executing task: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build C:\Dev\NoControl\Core3WinForms/Core3WinForms.csproj -o Z:/Core3WinForms/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/ <
>
> Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 16.0.225-preview+g5ebeba52a1 für .NET Core
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
> Wiederherstellung in "49,17 ms" für "C:\Dev\NoControl\Core3WinForms\Core3WinForms.csproj" abgeschlossen.
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview-009812\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(142,5): message NETSDK1057: Sie arbeiten mit einer Vorschauversion des .NET Core SDK. Sie können die SDK-Version über eine Datei "global.json" im aktuellen Projekt definieren. Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452. [C:\Dev\NoControl\Core3WinForms\Core3WinForms.csproj]
>     Core3WinForms -> Z:\Core3WinForms\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Core3WinForms.dll
>
> Der Buildvorgang wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
>       0 Warnung(en)
>       0 Fehler
>
> Verstrichene Zeit 00:00:02.63

excuting task: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build C:\Dev\NoControl\Core3WinForms/Core3WinForms.csproj -o Z:/Core3WinForms/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/ <
Should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Add two args "-o" and "OutputPath" instead of "-o OutputpPath"

Still not sure if this is a bug or a feature, and whose fault it really is, VSCode? MSBuild?
Maybe it is my fault using insider builds (VSCode) and previews (netcore 3), but that solution worked for me.

I am just posting to help others, not to push my rep, I couldn't care less tbh.

Comment: youre a life saver, i finally able to get it to work